# VBA Editor title bar buttons show up oddly large

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, icons, user-interface, title-bar

In VBA editor, there are buttons on the menu bar associated with objects like sheets, modules, forms, and classes. The buttons are the minimize, restore, and close buttons in the top right. They only show up when you have an object open. To my knowledge, Microsoft doesn't have a name for this group of buttons. Apple calls them Title Bar Buttons.

On my computer, the icons for these are large and I don't know why. The screenshots below show the various conditions. The buttons show up as large only when they're in alignment with the menu bar (i.e., when the object is maximized). It's not due to the Large Icons option because 1) it's disabled and 2) it only seems to affect the other toolbars.

Does anyone know why this is happening? It's not critical, but it's annoying and eats screen real estate.

---

No objects open:
[image: No Objects Open]

Workbook object open but not maximized:
[image: Open, Not Maximized]

Workbook object open and maximized:
[image: Open, Maximized]

Workbook object open and maximized with toolbar options set to have large icons:
[image: Open, Maximized, Large Icons]

Comment: Can you drag the top toolbar down, shift everything so nothing is in line with where the title bar icons show?

Comment: @Raystafarian I can drag the Menu Bar around but all the menus go with the icons. The second screenshot shows a workbook object not maximized and I can drag that around but, by default, all objects open maximized. The lost screen real estate is annoying but not enough to warrant restoring every window and resizing it to save the lost pixels.